# How to make future element draggable using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am reading the below api will make the currently available element on a page draggable.

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
```

but in my case I will be constructing new elements based on the user action. Like I will allow them to insert a text box over a image which should be draggable as well.

Is there a mechanism where I can attach this draggable feature using jquery using ".on()" ?

OR

I have to execute `$( "this" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });` every time when I create a new element?

Thanks for reading

Comment: you have to make the element draggable while creation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a mechanism where i can attach this draggable feature using jquery using ".on()" ?

No *(well, technically yes)*, you'll have to make each element draggable after you create it, or after some event that happens after it is created (such as mouseenter)

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".draggable:not(.initiated)", function() {
    $(this).draggable({ containment: "parent" }).addClass("initiated");
});
```

the initiated class prevents re-initializing the draggable every time you mouse over.

**Note**, you should use a better ancestor than document since mousenter is an event that will happen often on the document (will happen any time any element in the dom is moused into).